# Can I implement a vertical wrap of elements with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am implementing a drag-and-drop system to transfer elements to a container div. I would like these transferred elements to stay in a single column until they hit the container's height, then "wrap" to the next column, and so on.

Unfortunately the item count will not be pre-determined. Effectively I would like to end up with something that wraps elements into this kind of layout:

[image]

...with the elements loaded into the container in the order in which you see them here.

The `column-count` property is a nice idea, but it seems to spread the content to other columns before filling the available height.

Comment: Flexbox works great in everything except IE, so be sure to test it if you are supporting IE.  Using column-count should also work if you set the items in the container to `display: inline`.  Although it may depend on exactly what those elements are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.container {
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container div {
  text-align:center;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  color:white;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex but you need to set a max height for the container, which you'll probably need to set with javascript since your don't know the list's length.

You can use CSS columns instead, which doesn't need to know the number of items in advance. The downside is a lack of support for IE10 and below.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 2em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
  -moz-column-gap: 2em;
}

.container div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2em 0;
  background: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>  
</div>
```